# Page hangs because of large html code dynamically getting rendered

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular6

I am trying to display multiple descriptions which is in HTML format dynamically.
One of the description content contains huge html code [Having around 55k+ character in it]. Page hangs while rendering this piece of code.

```
<div *ngFor="let response of responseList">
    <div [innerHTML]="response.resDesc | bypassSecurityTrustHtml"></div>
</div>
```

How can I improvise this code which can handle any huge data that comes in.

This issue could be arising due to large number of child nodes in a single description

Comment: Try lazy loading

Comment: The best way is, don't load all the contents at a time. Give some option as load more or something like that.

Comment: @Tushar, issue is not about responseList array, it is about the single 'resDesc' in it.. which contains huge html code

Comment: Split the string to render and render its parts  only when needed (e.g. when you scroll down)